# Property of convex, two times differentiatable functions, concerning gradients

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

This is my first post here. I am looking for some hint, how to prove the following equation:

$$\nabla f(x)^\top x + \nabla f(-x)^\top(-x) \ge 0.$$

I have no clue, how this property is called. We just did some properties of convex functions, in particular if they are 1x or 2x differentiable. Does anyone know the name of this property or in which book to find it?

Thanks a lot
Cheers

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a specification of a more general property of $\nabla f$, known as [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_functional_analysis). In particular, a *set-valued* map $T : \Bbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \Bbb{R}^n$ is monotone if, for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, and $x^* \in T(x)$, $y^* \in T(y)$, we have
$$\langle x - y, x^* - y^* \rangle \ge 0.$$
Here, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ refers to the dot product, i.e. $\langle p, q \rangle = p^\top q$. I write it with alternate notation, because this concept does generalise beyond $\Bbb{R}^n$.$^1$ In this case, given $\nabla f$ is single-valued, this turns into,
$$\langle x - y, \nabla f(x) - \nabla f (y) \rangle = (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^\top(x - y) \ge 0,$$
for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^n$. What you have written is the special case where $y = -x$:
$$0 \le (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(-x))^\top(x - (-x)) = 2\nabla f(x)^\top x + 2\nabla f(-x)^\top(-x),$$
and dividing by $2$ yields the result.

Yes, it is true that gradient maps of convex functions are monotone.$^2$ As requested, here’s a hint how to prove it: recall that, if $f$ is convex, the tangent plane at $y \in \Bbb{R}^n$ minorises $f$. That is, for any $y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $\nabla f(y)^\top(x - y) + f(y) \le f(x)$ for all $x$. What if you swap the roles of $x$ and $y$?

---

$^1$ Indeed, the same definition works in Hilbert spaces, or if $X$ and $Y$ are paired Banach spaces (in particular, if $Y$ is the dual of $X$), then the same definition works for $T : X \rightrightarrows Y$ instead. But, you don’t have to concern yourself with this!

$^2$ In fact, we can even do without the differentiability! So long as $f$ is a proper, convex, lower-semicontinuous map, the [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) map $\partial f$ has the monotonicity property. This is a set-valued generalisation of the derivative used (primarily) for convex functions. When $f$ is convex and differentiable at $x$, $\partial f(x) = \{\nabla f(x)\}$, so it does generalise the derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much @TheoBendit! I had the suspicion, that it was a special case of the monotonicity property, but I was not sure. Thank you for your clarification! If I may ask one more question: Should I proof the general theorem and could it be, that there is a easier proof for the special case?

Comment: @JohnBlue I don’t think so, for no other reason that the general proof is short and straightforward.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time and effort to answer my questions. I had no clue how to start and where to look, now I see some light at the end of the tunnel. Have a nice weekend! :-)